# WSO2IS - Add captcha to Password Reset Flow

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2IS 5.3.0: For CSRF prevention purposes, we'd like to add captcha to the password reset via recovery email flow. It seems not too difficult to update our accountrecoveryendpoint jsps to do this, but I just wanted to double check if this something that's configurable already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form WSO2IS 5.8.0 onwards we support reCAPTCHA for password recovery and username recovery flow. Corresponding docs are https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Password+Recovery
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+reCaptcha+for+Password+Recovery

Comment: I will mark this as an accepted answer, though we have no intention of upgrading WSO2IS at this time